# Array values gets mutated while doing iteration with forEach and map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement some logic inn which i would like to have the array as it is, but when i tried to do with forEach and map the values in info array get mutated.

```
var info = [{"date":"today","location":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]},{"date":"yesterday","location":["a","b","c"]},{"date":"tomorrow","location":["a","b","c"]}]

var showItems = [];
var restrictItems= [];
info.forEach(res =>{
                if(res.location.length && restrictItems.length<5)
                {
                    let slicedLocation = res.location.slice(0,5-restrictItems.length);
                    slicedLocation.map((item, i) => {
                        
                            restrictItems.push(item);
                        
                    });
                    res.location = slicedLocation;
                    showItems.push(res);
                }
            })

console.log("showItemsshowItems",showItems);// here i am getting the output as [{"date":"today","location":["a","b","c","d","e"]}] which is expected
console.log("info",info)// here i am not getting the original value of info array(f,g,h) is missing in First array.
[{"date":"today","location":["a","b","c","d","e"]},{"date":"yesterday","location":["a","b","c"]},{"date":"tomorrow","location":["a","b","c"]}]
```

Please help here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clone `info` variable.

```
var cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(info))
```

And use `cloned` variable to keep `info`.

```js
var info = [{"date":"today","location":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]},{"date":"yesterday","location":["a","b","c"]},{"date":"tomorrow","location":["a","b","c"]}]
var cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(info))

var showItems = [];
var restrictItems= [];
cloned.forEach(res =>{
                if(res.location.length && restrictItems.length<5)
                {
                    let slicedLocation = res.location.slice(0,5-restrictItems.length);
                    slicedLocation.map((item, i) => {
                        
                            restrictItems.push(item);
                        
                    });
                    res.location = slicedLocation;
                    showItems.push(res);
                }
            })

console.log("showItemsshowItems",showItems);
console.log("info",info)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your original array to prevent mutation by using slice() method:

```js
let clonedInfo = info.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

First item of array: you slice it (0,5) (it means abcde), and assign it to 'slicedLocation', then you assign `res.location = slicedLocation;`. That is why your 'location' of first item contain only abcde